# PromQL - alerts when commands run over pods

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Is there a way to fire alerts when some run commands over pods like delete, exec, cp?
and alerts message should include in which namespace, which pod, which command, and who run these commands.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t what Prometheus does, it’s about metrics. For most api operations, you can use the audit log to check if they happen and why, but exec requests are complicated since they are opaque to the apiserver. The only tool I know of which can decode and log exec requests is Sysdig Trace and it isn’t supported on all platforms since it needs direct access to the control plane to do it.